# The locus of points from which tangents to a parabola make a constant angle is a hyperbola with the same focus as the parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

It is well known that when two tangents to a parabola are perpendicular to each other, they intersect on the directrix. In other words, the intersection point of the two tangents make a straight line, in this case, the directrix,

However, when the two tangents to a parabola intersect at another angle, it seems that the intersection point of the two tangents always forms a hyperbola, regardless of the angle. (The original problem I encountered asked the trace of the intersection point when the angle was 45degrees)

And surprisingly, the hyperbola has the same focus with the parabola.

This can be proven by brute-force algebra, with the same method used to prove the directrix property.

The question I'd like to ask is :
**Is there a geometric, or maybe an intuitive proof to why the trace of the intersection point forms a hyperbola, and why the focus of the hyperobla and parabola are the same?**

It can't be a coincidence that these two conic sections have the same focus, and I assumed that there would be a simple geometric observation that can be made to prove this property without algebra, as many other properties of the conic sections do, but I just can't seem to find it. My math teachers also seem to be stumped with this problem.

Can anyone give me help?
I couldn't find any proof regarding this property on google either.

(Sorry for my bad English; it is my first time writing mathematical topics in English, please correct me if anything is wrong)

Comment: If you can draw what you mean I would be happy to post it as part of your question.

Answer (score 4):

**PERHAPS THIS HELPS**

I've been thinking about your problem for a while. I wouldn't say that I could solve it. However, I have an idea that I would like to share with you.

You certainly [remember the Dandelin spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres) which may have something to do with your conjecture. The following figure depicts two cones (a black one and a grey one). These cones share the vertical axis and a Dandelin sphere. Tangent to this sphere there is a blue plane whose edge can be seen in the figure:

[image]

The blue plane and the black cone intersect in a parabola. Also, the blue plane intersects with the other cone in a hyperbola. The parabola's focus and one of the foci of the hyperbola are common.

My conjecture is that this is how to imagine your couple of parabola and hyperbola with a common focus.

Then, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your idea! It looks promising - I'll think about it too. I've never thought to look at the conic sections this way.

Comment: Conic sections are callad conic sections so that you look at them that way  : )

Answer (score 3):

Here a proof of a generalization of your statement in term of synthetic projective geometry.

> Let $\Gamma$ be a conic in a plane $\alpha$ and let $\Pi$ be a
>   projectivity of $\Gamma$ onto itself with axis $p$ and center $P$ not
>   contained in $p$. Then the locus of points of the intersections of the
>   $\Pi$-corrispondent tangents of $\Gamma$ is a conic $\Psi$.
>   Moreover $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ induces the same involution on $p$.

We identify a conic with its associated polarity in the plane.
Recall that a conic $\Gamma$ induces on a line $p$, not tangent to it, an involution which maps each point of p into the intersection of its polar with $p$.

First note that $p$ is not tangent to $\Gamma$ because it not contains its pole.
Let $D,E$ be the intersections (real or immaginary) of $p$ with $\Gamma$.
The projectivity $\Pi$ is determined by the image of a tangent $u$ to $\Gamma$.
Thus let $v=\Pi(u)$ and $A=u\cap v$.
If $U=\Gamma(u)$ and $V=\Gamma(v)$ are the respective contact points, then $\Pi(U)=V$. Moreover, $D$ and $E$ are fixed point of $\Pi$.

Let $\Delta$ be the (only) homography of the plane having $D,E,P$ as fixed points 
and mapping $U$ in $A$.
We claim that $\Delta$ maps $\Gamma$ onto a conic $\Psi$ which is the locus of the points of the form $t\cap\Pi(t)$ for $t$ tangent to $\Gamma$.

[image]

We first show that for each point $T$ of $\Gamma$ we have $\Delta(T)\subset t$, because $t=\Gamma(T)$ is the line tangent to $\Gamma$ at $T$.
Since $\Delta$ fixes $D$, it induces a projectivity of the pencil of the lines at $D$ into itself.
In particular, for each line $r$ containing $D$, $\Delta(r)$ is a line containing $D$ and $\Delta$ induces a perspectivity of $r$ onto $\Delta(r)$ whose center $C$ belongs to the line $e=PE$ which is tangent to $\Gamma$ and fixed by $\Delta$.
Similarly, $\Delta$ induces a perspectivity from $PU$ to $PA$ with center $J=p\cap u$.
Consequently, $\Delta(r\cap PU)=(r\cap PU)J\cap PA$ and $C=((r\cap PU)J\cap PA)(r\cap PU)\cap e=(r\cap PU)J\cap e$.
If $R=\Gamma(r)$, then $CR$ is tangent to $\Gamma$ by [Steiner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_conic#Steiner_generation_of_a_dual_conic).
This proves the assertion.

By a similar argument, also $\Delta(T)\subset\Pi(t)$ for each point $T$ of $\Gamma$. Consequently, we get $\Delta(T)=t\cap\Pi(t)$ for each point $T$ of $\Gamma$ where $t$ denote the tangent to $\Gamma$ at $T$.

It remains to show that $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ induces the same involution on $p$.
Let $X$ be a point of $p$ and $X'$ be its conjugate respect to $\Gamma$.
Then $DEXX'$ is an harmonic group, thus $DE\Delta(X)\Delta(X')$ is an harmonic group as well. But $\Delta(X)$ and $\Delta(X')$ are points of $p$ conjugated respect to $\Psi$ and this concludes the proof.

Finally we deduce your statement from this.
Let $\Gamma$ be a parabola, $p$ be its directrix and $P$ it focus.
A non-involutory projectivity $\Pi$ of $\Gamma$ into itself with center $P$ and axis $p$ induces on the line at infinity a non-involutory projectivity which commutes with the absolute involution, that's a direct congruence; consequently, $\Pi$ rotate each tangent line by the same angle.
Then $\Pi$ maps $\Gamma$ into a conic $\Psi$ which induces on $p$ (and $P$) the same involution as $\Gamma$, that's the right-angle involution.
This proves that $\Psi$ has focus $P$ and directix $p$ as well.
In order to show that $\Psi$ is an hyperbola, it's enough to prove that the line at infinity $w$ is secant $\Psi$. But this follows at once by noting that the point at infinity of the line $\Pi(w)$ belongs to $\Psi$ and it's no a contact point.

Answer (score 1):

**Not only do the parabola and hyperbola have the same focus, they also have the same directrix.**

Recall that a conic is the set of points for which the distance to the focus, divided by the distance to the directrix, equals the [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics))
$e$.

Now let's say a point $C$ lies outside a parabola with focus $F$, so the two tangents from $C$ to the parabola meet at an angle of $\theta$.

As shown in the diagram, let $A$ and $B$ be the points of tangency, and let $P_A$, $P_B$, and $P_C$ be the projections of these points onto the directrix.
[image: diagram is as described]
Looking at tangent point $A$, we see that since it lies on the parabola, it is equidistant from the focus $F$ and from the directrix,
so triangle $FAP_A$ is isosceles.

Furthermore, this triangle is cut in half by the line of tangency, $AC$, because it bisects angle $FAP_A$.
*(This is the same angle property as the "radio dish" property: The line $FA$, reflected off the tangent at $A$, is reflected straight upwards.)*
So $AC$ is the perpendicular bisector of $FP_A$.
So $CF=CP_A$.

Similarly, $BC$ is the perpendicular bisector of $FP_B$, and $CF=CP_B$.

Since $CP_A=CF=CP_B$, we can draw a circle centered at $C$, passing through $F$, $P_A$, and $P_B$.

This circle lets us see that angle $\angle P_A F P_B = \frac{1}{2} \angle P_A C P_B = \angle P_C C P_B$.

And the angle between lines $FP_A$ and $FP_B$ must be the same as the angle between their perpendicular bisectors, which is $\theta$ (or $\varphi=\pi-\theta$, depending on which angle you want). In our case, we have $\angle P_A F P_B = \varphi$, so $\angle P_C C P_B = \varphi$.

So $\cos(\varphi) = \frac{CP_C}{CP_B} = \frac{CP_C}{CF}$.

Thus $C$ lies on the hyperbola having the same focus and directrix as the parabola, but having eccentricity $\frac{1}{\cos(\varphi)} = \frac{-1}{\cos(\theta)}$.

**Comments**:
If we consider all points $C$ for which the parabola spans a given angle $\theta$, we get one branch of a hyperbola.  The parabola and directrix are both limiting cases of such a hyperbola branch.  If $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, the "negative eccentricity" just means the hyperbola branch lies *below* the directrix: We can think of the *signed distance* to the directrix being negative there.